# Find element by data attributes that use "|" as separators

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/69/)

HTML markup:

```
<div data-id='23|24|25'></div>
<div data-id='29|30|31'></div>
```

Script:

```
var array = [
  {
    "mid": "24"
  },
  {
    "mid": "26"
  },
  {
    "mid": "28"
  },
  {
    "mid": "29"
  },
  {
    "mid": "30"
  },
  {
    "mid": "31"
  }
];
var item_html ="";

$.each(array,function(i,k) {
  item_html = '<h3>'+k["mid"]+'</h3>';
  $('div[data-id="'+k["mid"]+'"').append(item_html); ???????????
});
```

Would it be possible to find the div element if part of the "|" separated value in its `data-id` matches the `mid`?

I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
<div data-id='23|24|25'>
  <h3>24</h3>
</div>
<div data-id='29|30|31'>
  <h3>29</h3>
  <h3>30</h3>
  <h3>31</h3>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `*=` selector (contains):

`$('div[data-id*="'+k["mid"]+'"').append(item_html);`

Comment: I don't think it will work if the number k['mid'] < 10.

Comment: Hm not, that's probably correct, actually. If `k['mid']` == 1, it would match 31, 21, 11, 10 etc..

Answer (score 1):

The result you are looking for is something tricky. I have update your code. hope this will help you.

```
var array = [
 { "mid": "24"},
 {"mid": "26"},
 {"mid": "28"},
 {"mid": "29"},
 {"mid": "30"},
 {"mid": "31"}
];
$('[data-id]').each(function(){   
  var $this = $(this), dataArr = $this.data('id').split('|'), i = 0;
  for(;i< dataArr.length; i++) {
    if(numInObjArr(array,dataArr[i])) {
       $this.append('<h3>'+ dataArr[i] +'</h3>');
    }
  }    
});

//function to check number in array object provided above
function numInObjArr(objArr, num){
  for (var i = 0, len=objArr.length; i< len; i++){
    if(objArr[i]["mid"] == num) {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/73/ to see the working example